# present modally view on already presented form sheet

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a form sheet modally presented on a view controller. On the form sheet, I want to modally present a another view. How can I achieve that? When I present a new view on form sheet it dismisses the form sheet and then present the new one. I want both the view presented modally.

Answer (score 1):

You can present only one view at a time.